# get Ident_Current from Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How to get `Ident_Current from linq`
I had tried this code but getting wrong data in return.

```
HamdeshDatabaseEntities hmd = new HamdeshDatabaseEntities();
int varMaxAdvertiseId = Convert.ToInt32(hmd.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Select IDENT_CURRENT ('HMDAdvertiseManage')").ToString());
```

When i execute Select IDENT_CURRENT ('HMDAdvertiseManage') on server it returns `CurrentId`.
but when i execute it through Linq in front end it always returns `-1`
I don't know why i'm getting this.
Please suggest me a better option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `SqlQuery` instead of `ExecuteSqlCommand`

```
HamdeshDatabaseEntities hmd = new HamdeshDatabaseEntities();
int varMaxAdvertiseId = Convert.ToInt32(hmd.Database.SqlQuery<decimal>("Select IDENT_CURRENT ('HMDAdvertiseManage')", new object[0]).FirstOrDefault());
```

`ExecuteSqlCommand` will return the number of rows affected by your INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statement. 
In your example it returns -1 because it hasn't affected any rows.